# How to remove selected dropdown values from other dropdown using lodash in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have four drop-downs:-

```
<div><label>Priority:</label>
    <label>First</label>
        <select ng-model="a.priority[0]" ng-change="selectPriority(a.priority[0])" data-ng-options="x for x in priorityArray">
                <option value="{{x}}"></option>
          </select>

        <label>Second</label>
          <select ng-model="a.priority[1]" ng-change="selectPriority(a.priority[1])" data-ng-options="x for x in priorityArray" >
                <option value="{{x}}"></option>
          </select>

        <label>Third</label>
          <select ng-model="a.priority[2]" ng-change="selectPriority(a.priority[2])" data-ng-options="x for x in priorityArray">
                <option value="{{x}}"></option>
          </select>

         <label>Fourth</label>
          <select ng-model="a.priority[3]" ng-change="selectPriority(a.priority[3])" data-ng-options="x for x in priorityArray">
                <option value="{{x}}"></option>
          </select>     
    </div>
```

I want to remove the selected option from one drop-down to remove from the other drop-downs.

My directive code:-

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.components')
        .directive('product', product);

    product.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout'];

    function product($http, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {},

            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                  scope.a = {};
                scope.priorityArray = ["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR"];

                $('#product').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
                    scope.a = {};
                });
                $('#product').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

                scope.selectPriority = function (priority) {
                    scope.selectedPriority = [];
                    scope.selectedPriority.push(priority);
                    scope.priorityArray = _.difference(scope.priorityArray, scope.selectedPriority);
                }
            },
            templateUrl: 'js/components/product.html'
        };
    }

})();
```

I am using the lodash filter for getting the filtered array in other drop-downs. Using current solution, the selected value filters the original dropdown(from which I selected the priority) too. I want the selected value to remain in the original dropdown. Keeping the different array for each drop-down is not an efficient solution. Can anyone suggest me some other solutions for this?

Comment: where do you use product directive?

Comment: in my index.html

Comment: can you try to use filter and see if that works